# calculating total retweets TO a user by JSON Parsing

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am calculating total number of retweets in C#,My Idea is to calulate the `retweeted_status` field in the JSON response.I am using JSON.NET.Is there any shorter way to calculate it?
Other way would be to create the classes and populate the Response and iterate theough the object.But I am looking for a shorter way because Its just a simple count.
Any one who can help me,
[This is JSON response](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=uxmangjx&count=200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do this by deserilaize the `json` into a `dynamic` object using `Json.Net`.

```
dynamic values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

and to iterate the values just cast it to `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
IDictionary<string, object> list = (IDictionary<string, object>)values;
```