# counting total objects in JSON Response

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, twitter, json.net

I want to count the number of objects [from this Response](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_to_user.json?screen_name=uxmangjx&count=100). I dont wnat to make classes for such a small purpose and then iterating over the classes. Is there any shorter way to do that.

I am using both JSON.NET and web.Serialization.

Comment: I think its almost the same question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373482/calculating-total-retweets-to-a-user-by-json-parsing/11373571#11373571

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving Number of Objects from JSON String in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746349/retrieving-number-of-objects-from-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Asif Instead of deleting the previous question ,I posted a new one because a deleting will down your rep.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im it is not duplicate ,the method you are telling require classes ,i already told tha i dont want ti use classes,creating classes and iterating over object is simple,I knew that

Comment: Man, did you tried converting json into Dictionary<string, object>? I think it would solve your problem.

Comment: @Asif I did that very earlier, IDictionary<string, object> list = (IDictionary<string, object>)values; how do I find what I require that is count?

Comment: Did you see the answer I am referring? It does not use json.net. In the same question another guy answered by json.net. Both are different.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im int length = ((ArrayList)csObj["data"]).Count;  what would you write instead of data? Have u saw my response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would return count of immediate objects in an array.

```
var input = "[{Name: 'Hello'}, {Name: 'Hi'}]";
dynamic response = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(input);
Response.Write(response.Length);
```

Comment: System.Array.Length' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Make sure you don't have method braces after response.Length. response.Length() is NOT valid.

Comment: Ali it is working but it is not giving correct result,Can you tell me what it actually returns from JSON response?