# Count of Json List without knowing the Type

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net, system.reflection

Using a GET API Method, I need get the count of all records of a table with Entity Framework. The method receives a table name and with this I get the assembly and get all records. But the result is a JSON and I have not found how to get the count of this.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    Type t = Type.GetType("Iwg.Transverse.Business." + tableName + "Manager, Iwg.Transverse.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("GetAll", Type.EmptyTypes);
    var executionMethod = method.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(t), null);
    JsonResult<object> json = this.Json(executionMethod);

    //This line does not work.
    //return this.Json(json .Count + 1);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return this.Json("Error getting the table " + tableName + "\nError " + e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question whether `GetAll` returns a JSON array, or whether it returns some kind of `IEnumerable` (or something else) which you are then converting into JSON.  (The text of the question seems to suggest the former, but the code seems to do the latter.)

If `GetAll` always returns a JSON string representing an array of items, then you could do the following to get the count:

```
int count = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse((string)executionMethod).Count;
```

If `GetAll` method always returns some kind of `IEnumerable` rather than JSON, you could do the following to get the count:

```
int count = ((IEnumerable)executionMethod).Cast<object>().Count();
```

(Note that you will need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code for this to work.)

If `GetAll` returns something else, such as a JSON *object* (not an array but maybe *containing* an array), or some other type of object, then we would need to know more details about what it is.

Comment: Sorry for not write entirely clear. The method GetAll return an IEnumerablem, and the result of Api is a JSON.

The second line is correct and works perfectly :D

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do a simple foreach loop separately to do this if there is no method available.

```
   int count=0;
    foreach (var package in json)
    {
        count = count++;
    }
return this.Json(count.ToString());
```

Edited response sourced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373749/counting-total-objects-in-json-response):

```
dynamic response = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
 return (response.Length);
```

Comment: This isn't work because json is a JsonResult, and the JsonResult objects do not have a public GetEnumerator definition

Comment: Its hard for me to troubleshoot this with what appears to be generic methods 'GetMethod' & 'Invoke' but give my edit a shot.

Comment: Not work. The json isn't a string object, only is an Object. Deserialize receive a string. But you gave me an idea. Cast the json to string. I go to look for that.

Thx